# Bug in Scala 2.10, Iterator.size?

Tags: scala, iterator

Is this normal?

```
scala> val x = Iterator(List[String]("str"))
lol: Iterator[List[String]] = non-empty iterator

scala> x.size
res1: Int = 1

scala> x.size
res2: Int = 0
```

And actually I'm meeting other weird errors.. a possible bug?

Comment: From http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Iterator "It is of particular importance to note that, unless stated otherwise, *one should never use an iterator after calling a method on it.* The two most important exceptions are also the sole abstract methods: next and hasNext."

Comment: Addendum to the answers: if you need a normal collection object, simply call e.g. `toSeq` or `toSet` on your iterator. Then discard the iterator and work on the collection.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No it's not a bug. It's the normal behavior.

Iterators are mutable things. You can think of them as pointers. Each time you ask an iterator to give you the next element it points to it will move one position further.

When you ask it to give you the size it will traverse each element in the sequence it points to, moving each time one position to the right. When it has no more elements to traverse `iterator.hasNext == false` it will return the size. But by then it will have exhausted all the elements. When a new call to `size` is made, the iterator is already positioned at the end, so it will immediately return 0.

To understand better what's happening, you can do this:

```
val it = Iterator(1, 2, 3, 4)
//it: >1 2 3 4
it.next() //ask for the next element
//it: 1 >2 3 4
it.next()
//it: 1 2 >3 4
println(it.size) // prints 2
//it: 1 2 3 4 >
println(it.size) // prints 0
```

Answer (score 8):

It's normal. To find out the size of an `Iterator`, you have to iterate through it until it is empty.

And then it's empty (size == 0).

Iterators are to be used with care, since they are very fragile data-structures.