# Spark accumulator causing application to silently fail

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an application that processes records in an rdd and puts them into a cache. I put a couple of [Spark Accumulators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/Accumulator.html) in my application to keep track of processed and failed records. These stats are sent to statsD before the application closes. Here is some simple sample code:

```
val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
val jdbcDF: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(...)).load().persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
logger.info("Processing table with " + jdbcDF.count + " rows")

val processedRecords = sc.accumulator(0L, "processed records")
val erroredRecords = sc.accumulator(0L, "errored records")

jdbcDF.rdd.foreachPartition(iterator => {
    processedRecords += iterator.length // Problematic line
    val cache = getCacheInstanceFromBroadcast()
    processPartition(iterator, cache, erroredRecords) // updates cache with iterator documents
}

submitStats(processedRecords, erroredRecords)
```

I built and ran this in my cluster and it appeared to be functioning correctly, the job was marked as a SUCCESS by Spark. I queried the stats using Grafana and both counts were accurate.

However, when I queried my cache, Couchbase, none of the documents were there. I've combed through both driver and executor logs to see if any errors were being thrown but I couldn't find anything. My thinking is that this is some memory issue, but a couple long accumulators is enough to cause a problem?

I was able to get this code snippet working by commenting out the line that increments *processedRecords* - see the line in the snippet noted with *Problematic line*.

Does anyone know why commenting out that line fixes the issue? Also why is Spark failing silently and not marking the job as FAILURE?

Comment: What is `recordCount`?

Comment: @ernest_k Ah, typo on my part, `recordCount` should be `processedRecords`, edited the post

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem with your `processedRecords` (not very familiar with Scala, though. But I think you should declare using `val processedRecords = sc.longAccumulator("processed records")` and increment using `processedRecords.add(iterator.length)`). I suspect the problem is in your `processPartition(iterator, cache, erroredRecords)` execution. Perhaps the right next step is to add some logging to `processPartition` and see what's happening there. Maybe it's just not saving (or has a dodgy error handler).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bug in Scala 2.10, Iterator.size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458066/bug-in-scala-2-10-iterator-size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application isn't "failing" per se. The main problem is, Iterators can only be "iterated" through one time.

Calling `iterator.length` actually goes through and exhausts the iterator. Thus, when `processPartition` receives `iterator`, the iterator is already exhausted and looks empty (so no records will be processed).

Reference [Scala docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/iterators.html) to confirm that `size` is "the number of elements returned by it. Note: it will be at its end after this operation!" -- you can also view the source code to confirm this.

**Workaround**

If you rewrite `processPartition` to return a long value, that can be fed into the accumulator.
Also, `sc.accumulator` is deprecated in recent versions of Spark.
The workaround could look something like:

```
val acc = sc.longAccumulator("total processed records")
...
df.rdd.foreachPartition(iterator => {
    val cache = getCacheInstanceFromBroadcast()
    acc.add(processPartition(iterator, cache, erroredRecords))
})
...
// do something else
```