# Count files in HDFS directory with Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs

In Scala, I am trying to count the files from an Hdfs directory.
I tryed to get a list of the files with `val files = fs.listFiles(path, false)` and make a count on it or get it's size, but it doesn't work as `files` type is `RemoteIterator[LocatedFileStatus]`

Any idea on how I should process ?

Thank's for helping

Comment: `RemoteIterator` has methods `hasNext()` and `next()` and so can be iterated over just like any other iterator to find its size. See the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458066/bug-in-scala-2-10-iterator-size

Comment: Actually files.size does not work. `Cannot resolve symbol size`. I already tryed to make a while loop to `while(files.hasNext)` and make a count in it, but it doesn't work eather

Comment: `Actually files.size does not work` that's expected because it's an iterator. Please read the answer in the page I posted in my first comment. `while(files.hasNext) { files.next(); count++; }` should work and if it doesn't you should edit your question to include a code stub and the error that you see.

Comment: What did you end up using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using:

```
var count: Int = 0
while (files.hasNext) {
  files.next
  count += 1
}
```

As a Scala begginer, I didn't know how to make a `count++` (the answear is `count += 1`). This actually works quiet well

Answer (score 0):

This has been done before but generally people use the FSImage. (A copy of the name node file.)

They'll then throw that into a hive table and then you can query it for information about your hdfs file system.

Here's a [really good tutorial](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Analyze-Small-FIle-in-HDFS/ta-p/246811) that explains how to export the fsimage and throw it into a hive table.

Here's another [that I think I prefer](https://prasanthkothuri.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/offline-analysis-of-hdfs-metadata/):

> Fetch and copy the fsimage file into HDFS
> #connect to any hadoop cluster node as hdfs user
>
> ```
> #downloads the fsimage file from namenode
> hdfs dfsadmin -fetchImage /tmp
>
> #converts the fsimage file into tab delimited file
> hdfs oiv -i /tmp/fsimage_0000000000450297390 -o /tmp/fsimage.csv -p Delimited
>
> #remove the header and copy to HDFS
> sed -i -e "1d" fsimage.csv
> hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp/fsimage
> hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/fsimage.csv /tmp/fsimage
>
> #create the intermediate external table in impala
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE HDFS_META_D ( 
>  PATH STRING , 
>  REPL INT , 
>  MODIFICATION_TIME STRING , 
>  ACCESSTIME STRING , 
>  PREFERREDBLOCKSIZE INT , 
>  BLOCKCOUNT DOUBLE, 
>  FILESIZE DOUBLE , 
>  NSQUOTA INT , 
>  DSQUOTA INT , 
>  PERMISSION STRING , 
>  USERNAME STRING , 
>  GROUPNAME STRING) 
> row format delimited
> fields terminated by '\t'
> LOCATION '/tmp/fsimage';
> ```

Once it's in a table you really can do the rest in scala/spark.